# rosmake vs make

Tags: rosmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a difference between rosmake and make? The way I understand it, rosmake is for building and updating the dependencies of a package, where these dependencies could be other ros packages.

rosdep is for installing dependencies outside the realm of ROS... More like system dependencies for building a ros package.

Then what is the purpose of running "make" in the directory of a ros package?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28292/rosmake-vs-make/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/10614/rosmake-vs-make#15661

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

make will only try to build the current package, ignoring the dependencies etc. Take a look at this answer: [rosmake-vs-make](http://answers.ros.org/question/10614/rosmake-vs-make)

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2